# Is it possible to build a Unity3d project on cloudbees?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cloudbees

Has anyone been able to use the [Jenkins Unity3d plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Unity3dBuilder+Plugin) to [build a unity project](http://unity3d.com/) on DEV@Cloud?
Is it even possible to build a unity project on this environment? Are there any detailed descriptions available?

Answer (score 1):

### No, you can't

I have no experience with CloudBees. But I did once set up building of Unity3D project on Jenkins. And apart from having a lot of "fun" with configuration of such a setup it **requires unity to be installed** on a Jenkins builder node. Since fast googling for "cloudbees unity3d" gives no info, I would say **it's impossible**.

### If you still want to do it

There is a service named [Tsugi](http://tsugi.co/)... I was thinking to use it, but never tried actually (since I was able to set up everything by myself). So, maybe you can use their service in conjunction (or instead of) cloudbees.

Answer (score 1):

Unity3d Editor runs on Windows and MacOSX. For Windows, I believe that the standard Cloudbees runs on top of Amazon WebService, which means machines without 3d cards. If so, Unity will fail.

I've made a test with a Amazon EC2 Windows 2008 SP2 instance today and it failed (see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24265 for some of the setup).

I haven't tried cloudbees MacOSX hardware (https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/Mobile/Mac+OS+in+the+Cloud+-+Machine+Specifications+), so  it could be that this works properly for this platform.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will be not able to install Unity3D on CloudBees slaves as you don't have enough privileges to install .exe, .rpm or .dmg files. However, you can rent a Windows, Linux or MAC machine on the cloud and use it as a slave tied to your Jenkins master on CloudBees. AWS offers Windows and Linux machines on the free tier, so maybe you can use them as a slave.